# Invalid Syntax error while making migrating

Tags: database, neo4j

I have installed neo4j database in django

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
    'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
}
}

NEO4J_DATABASES = {
'default' : {
    'HOST':'localhost',
    'PORT':8000,
    'ENDPOINT':'/db/data'
}
}
DATABASE_ROUTERS = ['neo4django.utils.Neo4djangoIntegrationRouter']
```

Models section:

```
#from django.db import models
from neo4django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse

class Customerr(models.NodeModel):
name=models.StringProperty()
email=models.StringProperty()
phno=models.StringProperty()
gender=models.StringProperty()
dp=models.StringProperty()
```

while executing the command:
    python manage.py makemigrations Food

```
PS C:\Users\Gaurav Pathak\Desktop\Swiggy> python manage.py makemigrations Food
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 8, in <module>
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
  File "C:\Users\Gaurav Pathak\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 54
    except ImportError,e:
                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last commit to [neo4django](https://github.com/scholrly/neo4django) was made 4 years ago, and its README states:

> The library is tested against Django 1.5.4 and Neo4j versions
>   1.8.2-1.9.4.

Those are very old versions of Django and neo4j, which is likely the cause of your issue.

You should change to a different approach to [using Python with neo4j](https://neo4j.com/developer/python/).

Comment: Can you please tell me the approach also